# Layers can't be edit because they are locked

Tags: grease-pencil, layers

[image]

My layers claim they are locked but the ones I am editing or at least trying  to edit are not allowing me to do so.

The one I am trying to erase is the background layer.

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this problem, coz I'm experiencing something similar

Comment: i came across a similar thing, and i think it happens because no layer is selected. clicking on a layer resolves it for me. And actually in your screenshot you're in draw mode in the object "Stroke" but the selected object is "Stroke.001", so it could be that as well